# How to get max values with groupby of entire dataframe in Pandas, not each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My output of my data frame looks like this.  I want to groupby `field id` to get the `max` `HourlyTempF`, `min` `HourlyTempF` and the `sum` of the `HourlyPrecipIn` of a 24 hour period.  My current solution gives the max for each row, which incidentally is the entire dataframe again.  I should Have three values for each field id.

I think the issue is that each row in my dataframe is it's "own dataframe", each row has header and columns so when I get `max`, `min`, `sum`, I get the present values for each row for each hour, I actually just want to group the entire data frame to give me an output like below and to create variables from the values in the desired output so I can put them in another dataframe.

**My code:**

```
`import pandas as pd
 import pandas


hrly_df = pd.DataFrame({'dateTime' :[t], 'field id': [id_], 'HourlyPrecipIn': [aPreVJ],'HourlyRH' : [aHumidVJ], 'HourlyTempF' : [aTempVJ]})


hrly_df = hrly_df[['dateTime','field id','HourlyPrecipIn','HourlyRH', 'HourlyTempF']]
hrly_df.head()
hrlydfs = hrLylst.append(hrly_df)


#GETS EACH MAX ROW INSTEAD OF MAX FOR DF
tempMax= hrly_df.groupby('field id')['HourlyTempF'].agg(['max'])
tempMax2 = tempMax.max().max()

# print 'Data successfully collected - writing to csv...'

tempDf = pd.DataFrame({'date' :[config.dayVal ], 'field id': [id_], 'DailyHighF': ['SHOULD BE MAX FROM hrly_df'],'DailyLowF' : ['SHOULD BE MIN FROM HRLY DF'], 'DailyPrecipIn' : ['SHOULD BE TOTAL FROM HRLY DF']})
```

**Current Output when I print tempMax**

`Starting import of field id: 40238
44.9
45.1
45.1
45.3
46.7
46.7
48.6
50.2
52.1
54.0
54.3
54.5
54.7
54.5
56.4
56.6
55.7
54.0
54.0
54.1
54.1
53.6
52.2
Starting import of field id: 3402
44.9
45.1
45.1
45.3
46.7
46.7
48.6
50.2
52.1
54.0
54.4
54.5
54.7
54.5
56.5
56.6
55.7
54.1
54.0
54.1
54.2
53.6
52.2
Starting import of field id: 45883
45.3
45.6
45.7
45.9
47.1
47.3
49.1
50.7
52.7
54.3
54.8
55.0
55.2
55.0
57.1
57.5
56.2
54.6
54.4
54.6
54.6
53.8
52.7`

**Desired Output:**

```
field id | max temp  | min temp | total precip
40238      56.4         44.9        0.06
3402       56.6         44.9        0.06
45883      57.7         45.3        0.06
```

**Current Dataframe**
`dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 01:00:00    40238             0.0      98.8         44.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 02:00:00    40238             0.0      98.9         45.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 03:00:00    40238             0.0      98.7         45.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 04:00:00    40238            0.02      99.6         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 05:00:00    40238             0.0      95.0         46.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 06:00:00    40238             0.0      99.8         46.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 07:00:00    40238            0.02      95.6         48.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 08:00:00    40238             0.0      94.4         50.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 09:00:00    40238            0.01      93.6         52.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 10:00:00    40238             0.0      93.6         54.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 11:00:00    40238            0.01      93.5         54.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 12:00:00    40238             0.0      87.3         54.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 13:00:00    40238             0.0      86.1         54.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 14:00:00    40238             0.0      88.0         54.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 15:00:00    40238             0.0      82.1         56.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 16:00:00    40238             0.0      85.5         56.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 17:00:00    40238             0.0      82.9         55.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 18:00:00    40238             0.0      82.6         54.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 19:00:00    40238             0.0      79.1         54.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 20:00:00    40238             0.0      83.8         54.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 21:00:00    40238             0.0      87.9         54.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 22:00:00    40238             0.0      88.6         53.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 23:00:00    40238             0.0      87.5         52.2
Starting import of field id: 3402
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 01:00:00     3402             0.0      98.7         44.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 02:00:00     3402             0.0      98.8         45.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 03:00:00     3402             0.0      98.7         45.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 04:00:00     3402            0.01      99.5         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 05:00:00     3402             0.0      95.0         46.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 06:00:00     3402             0.0      99.7         46.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 07:00:00     3402            0.02      95.6         48.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 08:00:00     3402             0.0      94.5         50.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 09:00:00     3402            0.01      93.6         52.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 10:00:00     3402             0.0      93.6         54.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 11:00:00     3402            0.01      93.5         54.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 12:00:00     3402             0.0      87.3         54.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 13:00:00     3402             0.0      86.0         54.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 14:00:00     3402             0.0      87.9         54.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 15:00:00     3402             0.0      82.0         56.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 16:00:00     3402             0.0      85.4         56.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 17:00:00     3402             0.0      82.9         55.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 18:00:00     3402             0.0      82.6         54.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 19:00:00     3402             0.0      79.2         54.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 20:00:00     3402             0.0      83.8         54.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 21:00:00     3402             0.0      87.9         54.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 22:00:00     3402             0.0      88.6         53.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 23:00:00     3402             0.0      87.5         52.2
Starting import of field id: 45883
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 01:00:00    45883             0.0      97.9         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 02:00:00    45883             0.0      97.9         45.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 03:00:00    45883             0.0      97.7         45.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 04:00:00    45883             0.0      99.0         45.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 05:00:00    45883             0.0      95.5         47.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 06:00:00    45883             0.0      99.0         47.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 07:00:00    45883            0.03      95.3         49.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 08:00:00    45883             0.0      95.2         50.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 09:00:00    45883            0.01      94.0         52.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 10:00:00    45883            0.02      93.3         54.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 11:00:00    45883            0.04      92.9         54.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 12:00:00    45883             0.0      86.9         55.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 13:00:00    45883             0.0      84.7         55.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 14:00:00    45883             0.0      87.3         55.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 15:00:00    45883             0.0      81.9         57.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 16:00:00    45883             0.0      83.4         57.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 17:00:00    45883             0.0      82.5         56.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 18:00:00    45883             0.0      82.1         54.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 19:00:00    45883             0.0      80.1         54.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 20:00:00    45883             0.0      83.9         54.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 21:00:00    45883             0.0      87.4         54.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 22:00:00    45883             0.0      88.4         53.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-22 23:00:00    45883             0.0      87.5         52.7`

Comment: That is a ton of extra lines of data to scroll through. It would be helpful to show fewer representative lines rather than several hundred individual lines. We should be able to copy/paste from your question to test and help you more effectively. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Note that the values I see may be different slightly, due to errors introduced in copy/pasting your data, but the simplest way to get (what I assume) is your output is to use `groupby` on the columns with the `agg()` function with a dictionary of aggregations.

Here is how the data looks in my testing DF:

```
    dateTime    field       id      HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH    HourlyTempF
0   2019-05-22  01:00:00    40238   0.0             98.8        44.9
0   2019-05-22  02:00:00    40238   0.0             98.9        45.1
0   2019-05-22  03:00:00    40238   0.0             98.7        45.1
0   2019-05-22  04:00:00    40238   0.02            99.6        45.3
0   2019-05-22  05:00:00    40238   0.0             95.0        46.7
0   2019-05-22  06:00:00    40238   0.0             99.8        46.7
```

If your data is coming in as individual rows, then getting it in a single dataframe may be another issue altogether.

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'HourlyTempF':[max,min],'HourlyPrecipIn':sum})

        HourlyTempF     HourlyPrecipIn
        max     min     sum
id          
3402    56.6    44.9    0.05
40238   56.6    44.9    0.06
45883   57.5    45.3    0.10
```

Comment: This doesn't work because my dataframe has all 0 indices which causes me to get the max, sum, min, of each row and not the entire dataframe

Comment: What you posted does not look like a dataframe, it looks like an individual collection of rows. Please see my edit, as your initial df format is unclear